# How to use VIM(buffer) for quick editing of clipboard content

Tags: macos, vim, command-line, alfred

Being spoiled by the awesome VIM mode on ZSH I wanted to recreate the same experience for my clipboard. VIM mode in ZSH allows the current command to be edited in a VIM buffer an to be written back to the command-line, example:

[Example of VIM mode on ZSH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVbZ1.gif)

I want to recreate the same experience for my clipboard (on macOS). I got it working using the following mini script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile=/tmp/$(openssl rand -base64 8)

touch $tmpfile
pbpaste > $tmpfile
vim $tmpfile
pbcopy < $tmpfile
rm $tmpfile
```

I have a feeling this could be a lot easier. What I want to accomplish is:
1. Open VIM (command-line) with the current content of the system clipboard
2. Edit the content in VIM
3. On write out, copy the content back to the system clipboard

The end-goal is to get this in a Alfred workflow that allows me to quickly edit clipboard content on the fly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with some of the commands on macOS, but on Linux you can access the clipboard contents with `xclip`. So you can do something like `$ xclip -o | vim` which sends the clipboard contents to vim, and then from within vim run `: w !xclip -i` which sends the contents of the buffer to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires the `vipe` tool (which stands for vi pipe, I think): I have a bash function called `pbed` that does exactly what you ask:

```
pbed () {
  pbpaste | vipe | pbcopy
}
```

You could easily turn that into a script. You can get vipe from brew in the moreutils package.

Comment: Install vipe with `brew install moreutils`

Answer (score 0):

I have this on my zshrc:

```
# Edit content of clipboard on vim (scratch buffer)
function _edit_clipboard(){
    # pbpaste | vim -c 'setlocal bt=nofile bh=wipe nobl noswapfile nu'
    pbpaste | vim
}
zle -N edit-clipboard _edit_clipboard
bindkey '^x^v' edit-clipboard
```

Comment: Don’t you need `vim -`? And this doesn’t set the clipboard contents after the edits.

Comment: Sorry, my vim is aliased to neovim and it does not require -
Actually I have added some comments on my code, so other people don't have any problems